# Equivalent of boost::file_system::no_check in boost::filesystem V3?

Tags: c++, boost-filesystem

`boost::filesystem::no_check` does not seem to exist in `boost::filesystem` version 3 (boost v1.54). What is the appropriate equivalent in the newer version of the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [constructors of path in 1.55.0](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path), you will notice that the name checking feature was removed.
Additionally [this deprecated features table](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/deprecated.html) indicates that name checking was removed. The simple work around for `path(const string_type& str, name_check)` which existed in 1.49.0  consisted of ignoring `name_check`.

As you don't want to check the name anyway simply omit it.